# Need DefaultAppPool in the administrators group to run vb script

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, vbscript

I'm trying to run a VB script from C# code accessed through a web page. The web site is using impersonation and is running in an app pool that's using the AppPoolIdentity option. I'm getting the error regarding 'Loading settings failed', which I've seen other posts and web searches say is related to registry access and certain script host keys missing. I've been through all of that and haven't got it to work. I've added the keys, set permission on the hives and such.

The only thing I have been able to do to get it working is either adding the DefaultAppPool service account to the administrators group or otherwise making the app pool use an administrator account. This is likely not an acceptable solution for a production web site.

I've used process monitor to attempt to find the problem and I don't see it. I can see the w3wp app call cscript but I don't see any access denied or other errors.

I'm looking for some hints on how I might narrow this down to the resource that is causing the problem. I'm running this on my dev machine at the moment, its Win 7 64 bit, IIS 7.5, the app is in ASP.Net 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly please don't make anything an administrator account. It'd be useless anyway as you say you're using impersonation - so the app pool identity will hardly be used.

What is the VBScript file trying to do? Given VBScript isn't that difficult and if it tries to do anything complicated it's going to call COM it shouldn't be that difficult to move it into a C# class and have it run in the correct context of your application (and that way you'll get better error messages if you're lucky)

Answer (score 0):

You can also load a script engine and run vbs in your program.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adcae113-4758-481a-a367-60d5d14d97d6/this-is-how-to-turn-vbs-and-js-files-into-exe-files-from-the-command-line-without-third-party-tools?forum=scripting